# Angular 2+ parent / child routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have these two routes set up

```
{ path: 'manage-brands', component: ManageBrandsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

{ path: 'manage-brand/:brandId',  component: BrandAdminComponent },
```

But what I really want is this:
/manage-brands -> ManageBrandsComponent
and then should there be an id in the route
/manage-brands/brandId -> BrandAdminComponent

Is there a way to achieve this using children: [ ] or do I have to render an ng-template based on a RouteSnapshot using just one component?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask is the /manage-brand/:brandId route not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Parent-Child way to achieve this behavior.

```js
const routes: Routes = [

{
    path: 'manage-brands', component: ManageBrandsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: ':brandId', component: BrandAdminComponent }
    ]
}

]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I have tried this method and the route seems to load ManageBrandsComponent when on the child route.